# How to apply constraints with javax.validation.constraints groups from Swagger with SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I have a SpringBoot project, this has two methods that receive the same type of object as a parameter, for each case there are different validations in its properties, this elegantly using groups of javax.validation.constraints, now when applying OpenApi-Swagger documentation to the project Everything works very well, except that the Swagger interface shows as required all the validations in the two methods, it is not able to distinguish the validation applied by groups.

How to apply constraints with javax.validation.constraints groups from Swagger with SpringBoot?

interfaces for groups:

```
    public interface OnCreate {}

    public interface OnDelete {}
```

object with validations on properties with groups:

```
    @NotBlank(groups = { OnUpdate.class, OnDelete.class }, message = "codigo obligatorio")
    @NotNull(groups = { OnUpdate.class, OnDelete.class }, message = "codigo obligatorio")
    @Length(groups = { OnUpdate.class }, min = 6, max = 6, message = "cantidad de caracteres permitida 6")
    private String codigo;

    @NotNull(groups = { OnUpdate.class, OnCreate.class }, message = "mail obligatorio")
    @NotBlank(groups = { OnUpdate.class, OnCreate.class }, message = "mail obligatorio")
    @Email(groups = { OnUpdate.class, OnCreate.class }, message = "mail mal formado")
    @Length(groups = { OnUpdate.class, OnCreate.class }, min = 1, max = 150, message = "cantidad maxima de caracteres 150")
    private String mail;

    @NotBlank(groups = { OnUpdate.class, OnCreate.class }, message = "nombre obligatorio")
    @NotNull(groups = { OnUpdate.class, OnCreate.class }, message = "nombre obligatorio")
    @Length(groups = { OnUpdate.class, OnCreate.class }, min = 1, max = 150, message = "cantidad maxima de caracteres 150")
    private String nombre;

    @NotNull(groups = { OnUpdate.class, OnCreate.class }, message = "telefono obligatorio")
    @Max(groups = { OnUpdate.class, OnCreate.class }, value = 2147483647, message = "cantidad maxima de caracteres 2147483647")
    @Min(groups = { OnUpdate.class, OnCreate.class }, value = -2147483648, message = "cantidad maxima de caracteres -2147483647")
    private Integer telefono;
```

and services:

```
         @Validated
         public class PersonaRest extends GeneralRest {
         @PostMapping("/actualizar")
         @Validated(OnUpdate.class)
         public ResponseEntity editar(@Valid @RequestBody PersonaTO p) {
             logger.info("La persona update: " + p.toString());
             return new ResponseEntity(personaServicio.agregar(p), HttpStatus.OK);
         }

         @PostMapping("/eliminar")
         @Validated(OnDelete.class)
         public ResponseEntity eliminar(@Valid @RequestBody PersonaTO p) {
             logger.info("La persona eliminar: " + p.toString());
             try {
                 personaServicio.eliminar(p);
                 return new ResponseEntity(Boolean.TRUE, HttpStatus.OK);
             } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
                 return new ResponseEntity(
                         new CustomErrorMessages("No se encontro una persona con el identificador " + p.getCodigo()),
                         HttpStatus.OK);
             }

         }

     }
```

service update
[image]
service remove
[image]

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I don't think that swagger is considering Springs Validated annotation. It only checks for Bean Validation annotations.

Comment: It's worth noting that you can get around needing to specify both of your groups in validation annotations which should apply to both. Your group interfaces can both extend `javax.validation.groups.Default` so that they also pick up validation annotations without a specified group